# How to get text content with puppeteer and test it

Tags: testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I am trying to **scrape** some text and than compare it in jest except.

My code:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
```

Returns:

Expected: `Forgot password`

Received: `{}`

```
describe("login to Synthrone tests", () => {
  test("no existed user try", async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://admin.manager.test-synthrone.com/");
    const a = page.evaluate(() =>
      document.querySelector(".additional-user-actions").textContent.trim()
    );
    expect(a).toBe("Forgot password");
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try adding a `await page.waitForSelector('.additional-user-actions');` before?

Comment: you also need to add  `await ` right after const a like as `const a = await ... `

Comment: I tried both tips but is stil does not working